# Youtube Thumbnail upload Failing with API

Tags: go, youtube-data-api, thumbnails

I am trying to upload a thumbnail for youtube video in this way:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    url := "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set?videoId=kU7okI-_vvU&key=[API_KEY]Type=media"
    imageRef, err := os.Open("test.png")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("os.Open", err)
    }
    rd := bufio.NewReader(imageRef)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, rd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("http.NewRequest", err)
    }

    log.Println(req.Body)

    req.Header.Add("authorization", "Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]")
    req.Header.Add("content-type", "image/png")

    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("http.DefaultClient", err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ioutil.ReadAll", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(res)
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

I am getting this response:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request does not include the image content.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request does not include the image content.",
        "domain": "youtube.thumbnail",
        "reason": "mediaBodyRequired",
        "location": "body",
        "locationType": "other"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am including the image body in the POST request. Yet the respose says *"The request does not include the image content."*. Can anyone please help with this.

API requires that max file size be 2MB and I have ensured this.

Thank you.

PS: Although not shown in the code, result is tested with error handling.

Comment: Please don't ignore errors.

Comment: @Marc  Although not shown in the code, the result is tested with error handling. I just omitted here to keep the code crisp.

Comment: Assuming you properly checked all errors (this is why it's better to put it in the code), try setting the `Content-Type` header to `image/png`.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for the suggestion. But no luck! It still throws the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bare HTTP methods for invoking YouTube Data API can be quite tricky at times.

You should have been employing the [Google API Client Library for Go](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client) instead. See also the [official Go Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/go).

In case you stick with your current code, you need to have the following:

- the invoking URL should contain the parameter `uploadType=media`, and
- the `Content-Type` header should be passed on to the HTTP call with a value of kind `image/png` (as already suggested above).
- the `Content-Length` header should also be set by your code (since that's not done within the [`NewRequestWithContext`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go#L838) function; see also this function's [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequestWithContext), as @Peter indicated below).

---

Also you have to change your URL, since, according to the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set#http-request), the API endpoint's URL is:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/thumbnails/set`.

Do notice that your URL is missing the `/upload/` path component.

Comment: The content length is only inferred from a *bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Reader, or *strings.Reader. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#NewRequestWithContext (last paragraph)

Comment: Please try setting `Content-Length` too.

Comment: The parameter `uploadType=media` is required, even though it's not documented; it can be found in client libraries source code.

Comment: See the implementation of that API endpoint in [youtube/v3/youtube-gen.go](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/2abcd8ee53ac684a33dc52237960dda39abce063/youtube/v3/youtube-gen.go#L24544)